# In R Studio, how can I stop my for-loop from overwriting stored output with the most recent output?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I've build a for-loop that should store the first and surname of a soccer  player (scraped from a website) in separate columns, but the for-loop keeps overwriting all stored results with the most recent output.

```
noplayers <- 3 # the amount of players I want to run the loop for while testing my code
playeridtest <- playerid[1:noplayers] # assign the three IDs to a vector
playernames <- rep(NA, noplayers) 
playernames <- as.data.frame(playernames) # Create an empty data frame to store results in
playernames$id <- playeridtest # Add the three player IDs to the ID column

for(i in playeridtest){
  scoresway <- paste("http://www.scoresway.com?sport=soccer&page=person&id=",i, sep="")
  scoresway <- read_html(scoresway)
  urlnodescorefirst <- html_node(scoresway, "dd:nth-child(2)")
  urltextscorefirst <- html_text(urlnodescorefirst)
  playernames$first <- urltextscorefirst
  urlnodescoresur <- html_node(scoresway, "dd:nth-child(4)")
  urltextscoresur <- html_text(urlnodescoresur)
  playernames$sur <- urltextscoresur
}
```

Using the test vector of 3 player IDs to find the first and surnames, it keeps storing the name of the third player three times. (Lahm's ID = 14)

```
id first    sur
4  Philipp Lahm
11 Philipp Lahm
14 Philipp Lahm
```

Comment: Add [i] at the end of each of the vector names (e.g, `playernames$first[i]`). That will create a vector of all the results. of course, you'll also need it in subsequent calls on the data (`read_html(scoresway[i])`)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I've tried adding it to everything in this manner:
 ...
  scoresway[i] <- read_html(scoresway[i])
  urlnodescorefirst[i] <- html_node(scoresway[i], "dd:nth-child(2)")
  urltextscorefirst[i] <- html_text(urlnodescorefirst[i])
  playernames$first[i] <- urltextscorefirst[i]
  urlnodescoresur[i] <- html_node(scoresway[i], "dd:nth-child(4)")
  urltextscoresur[i] <- html_text(urlnodescoresur[i])
  playernames$sur[i] <- urltextscoresur[i]
...
But this gave me: Error: 'NA' does not exist in current working directory 

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: My fault for not realizing you did `i in playeridtest`. See my answer below for a fix to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i in seq_along(playeridtest)) { # Note change here
  scoresway <- paste("http://www.scoresway.com?sport=soccer&page=person&id=",playeridtest[i], sep="")
  scoresway <- read_html(scoresway)
  urlnodescorefirst <- html_node(scoresway, "dd:nth-child(2)")
  urltextscorefirst <- html_text(urlnodescorefirst)
  playernames$first[i] <- urltextscorefirst
  urlnodescoresur <- html_node(scoresway, "dd:nth-child(4)")
  urltextscoresur <- html_text(urlnodescoresur)
  playernames$sur[i] <- urltextscoresur
}
```

Result:

```
playernames
  playernames id   first          sur
1          NA  4 Maarten Stekelenburg
2          NA 11  Robert         Huth
3          NA 14 Philipp         Lahm
```

The column of playernames$playernames is a result of the code you included at the top. Just skip these two lines, and replace with the third:

```
# playernames <- rep(NA, noplayers) 
# playernames <- as.data.frame(playernames)
playernames<-NULL
```

Comment: Oh my word, thank you so much! I've been struggling with this for a while. If it's not too much to ask, could you explain why the way I constructed the for-loop did not work and seq_along (combined ith the playeridtest[i] in the paste function) did?

Comment: You're welcome. When you do `i in d`, then each i is the contents of the nth element in `d` - in this case, the player's ID number. When using `seq_along(d)` instead, each i is simply the index of the player ID number you're interested in. But I think the real problem was with using [i] in scoresway because of the type of data that's returned from `read_html`.